# parallel tests using jUnit5 @ParameterizedTest and csvSource

Tags: junit, parallel-processing, junit5

I've found out Junit5 supports parallelism since version 5.3, but i din't find any reference to how run parallel tests using a csv source. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can create `src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties` with the same content:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
```

Answer (score 0):

configuring failsafe plugin as follow does that

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <!--override configuration from parent pom-->
    <configuration combine.self="override">
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default =concurrent
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As explained here https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution .This works also for parameterized tests